Lipschitz function approximated by smooth functions with zero a regular value
Consider a Lipschitz function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. Then I want a family of smooth functions $f_\epsilon : \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, such that $f_\epsilon\to f$ uniformly on compact sets, and $0$ is a regular value of $f_\epsilon$ for every epsilon, i.e. if $f_\epsilon(x)=0$ then $df_\epsilon(x)\ne 0$.
Now using the standard  mollifier $\phi_\epsilon$ we can define $f_\epsilon=f*\phi_\epsilon$, these are all smooth functions, such that $f_\epsilon \to f$ converges uniformly in compact subsets. But it's not obvious to me that $0$ is a regular value of $f_\epsilon$. I want to make the following claim :

For all $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, there exists a Lipschitz vector field $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $X(f_\epsilon)(x)>\delta$ for some $\delta>0$, whenever $f_\epsilon(x)=0$.

Now if such a vector field exists, then since $X(f_\epsilon)(x)=X(x)\cdot \nabla f_\epsilon(x)$, we see the gradient cannot be zero. Is it true that such a vector field will exist? If so, how to construct it and show it satisfies the desored properties? I'm not sure if we need more assumptions, but I am actually mainly interested in the case when $f=0$ is the boundary of a polytope, so any help in that specific situation would also be appreciated.
The idea I had for trying this is try and cover the compact subset $f\ge 0$ by open balls. Then this union of balls would be a smooth, open submanifold. Then maybe we can try to construct the outward pointing normal vector field, and maybe it can be useful? I'm not really able to do anything with this idea, but any hints or suggestions or links to references where they treat such a problem would be very welcome.

By Sard's theorem $\exists o_\epsilon \in (0,\epsilon)\colon df_\epsilon(x) \ne 0$ when $f_\epsilon(x) = o_\epsilon$. Substitute $f_\epsilon$ by $f_\epsilon - o_\epsilon$.
